Why stable diffusion webui does not correctly generate pictures?
Certainly! Here’s an expanded version of your question for Stack Overflow:

Question:
Hi, I’m new to using Stable Diffusion WebUI, and I’m encountering an issue with image generation. Whenever I try to generate an image using a specific model, the output is always blank or empty. I’ve checked my settings, and everything seems correct, but the generated content is still empty.
I’m using the flux model and have ensured that my hardware setup meets the basic requirements for Stable Diffusion. Other models sometimes work, but with this one, I consistently get an empty output.
I’d appreciate any insights on what might be causing this or tips for troubleshooting in Stable Diffusion WebUI. I’m particularly interested in:

Verifying model compatibility and integrity
Adjusting settings that could help resolve this issue
Understanding if any specific configurations or dependencies are required for certain models

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can offer!


A1111 doesnt support flux, you need to use Forge UI, Reforge UI or Comfy UI for Flux support, read up on the documentation on civit.ai for a detailed explanation plus the additional VAE and text encoders that are missing
